# Continue on a specific await

Tags: c#, async-await

Let's say that we have the following method:

```
public async Task HandleAsync(MessageContext context, RegisterAccount account)
{
    var user = blabla;
    await _repository.CreateAsync(user);
    await _emailHandler.Send(new ActivationEmail(user));

    await _context.WaitForAsync<AccountActivated>(x=> x.AccountId == user.Id);

    user.Activate();
    _repository.UpdateAsync(user);
}
```

On the `WaitForAsync` invocation I release the internal messaging service and thus allowing it continue processing other messages. So this class instance is just waiting on my custom awaiter.

This works well.

However, I also persist the state to be able to exit the application and then continue after a process restart. If I used separate methods this would work fine (just invoke the continuation method).

But since async/await rewrite the code, would it be possible to tell .NET to continue on after the "WaitForAsync" when the correct message is received after the restart? (i.e. create the class, set the state, tell it to continue after the `WaitForAsync` line instead from invoking the method from start)

*(yes, I just have basic knowledge about how async/await change the code, hence the question)*

Comment: No, you are supposed to put that code after `await _context.WaitForAsync`. Otherwise you might want an event-based system rather than an async-based one.

Comment: As a side note, you might be missing an `await` on the last line.

Comment: Can you persist something extra in your state that indicates that condition (if it's not already determinable) and `if()` out the first few lines of `HandleAsync()` when that occurs?

Comment: There will be no synchronization context after application restart. You can have some kind of queue where you keep all state information for every message. After restart you retreive this queue and continue processing.

Answer (score 0):

> would it be possible to tell .NET to continue on after the "WaitForAsync" when the correct message is received after the restart?

No. The best solution is to have a queue of incoming messages as Fabio suggested, with a (possibly asynchronous) "consumer" handling those messages. This may be naturally represented using Reactive Extensions, or possibly TPL Dataflow.